# Creating A DialogBox from a DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, win32gui

I have a need to create a DialogBox from a DLL (Not using MFC). The `DialogBox` is created but not shown anywhere in the UI. Its message Loop runs. it receives all the messages but it does not show!. The Scenario is as follows.

There are 2 Exe's and a DLL.

**Process A** : Calls **Process B** using `CreateProcess` with flags `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NO_WINDOW |CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`.

**Process B** : Loads a DLL using `LoadLibrary` and calls a function that will invoke the `DialogBox`.

The Resource file for the dialog box is as follows

```
IDD_MSGHLDR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 276, 83
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_NOFAILCREATE | DS_CENTER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Notification"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",ID_INSTALL_OK,164,62,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",ID_INSTALL_CANCEL,219,62,50,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MSG,7,7,262,40,ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_BORDER | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MSG_TIMEOUT,7,59,145,17,ES_READONLY | NOT WS_BORDER
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MSGHLDR AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0,
    0, 0, 100, 100,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 100, 100,
    0, 0, 0, 0
END
```

The `DialogBox` is created using

`DialogBox(currentDLLInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MSGHLDR), NULL,DialogProc);`

And the DialogProc functions is as follows.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DriverDialogProc(_In_ HWND   hwndDlg, _In_ UINT   uMsg, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            hCurrentMessageHandler = hwndDlg;
            //(SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDC_MSG, messageToDisplay.c_str())) ? PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => Setting Message %s SUCCESS", messageToDisplay.c_str()) : PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => Setting Message %s FAILED", messageToDisplay.c_str());
            if (applicationCode == ApplicationCode::PMP)
                SetWindowText(hwndDlg, (LPCSTR)PMP_TEXT);
            else
                SetWindowText(hwndDlg, (LPCSTR)DC_TEXT);
            //SetTimer(hwndDlg, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC)CountDown);
            //ShowWindow(hwndDlg, SW_SHOW);
            return FALSE;
        case WM_SETTEXT:

            PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => Setting Title : %s", (LPCSTR)lParam);
            return FALSE;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => Rcvd WM_COMMAND WITH Wparam H : %d , L : %d", HIWORD(wParam), LOWORD(lParam));
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_INSTALL_OK:
                    PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => User clicked OK");
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, PROCEED);
                    return TRUE;
                case ID_INSTALL_CANCEL:
                    PrintLog("\t[DRV_MSG_HANDLER] => User clicked Cancel");
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, SKIP);
                    return TRUE;
            }
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I Have no issues with both the processes or the DLL. All work as intended.
The Dialog's message Loop runs fine. It prints the LOGS fine, but the Actual dialog is not visible anywhere. I'm on VS 2017. There is no return code from the `DialogBox` as it is still waiting for `EndDialog` which is not possible since the UI isn't there.

Things i've tried :

1. `while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE));` just before the call to DialogBox
2. Creating a separate project and try out this scenario (It works there).
3. Creating a Simple `MessageBox`. (FAILS).

All the Exe's are Console applications. Not win32 projects. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Hans Passant I did try passing in GetDesktopWindow() too with no success. What would you suggest ?

Comment: So you are saying that everything is fine with the code?. and the points of failure could only be CREATE_NO_WINDOW?. As I said ,`Creating a separate project and try out this scenario (It works there).` It worked there. How would one explain that?. The test project also used CREATE_NO_WINDOW. @HansPassant

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you. Well, cant modify `CreateProcess` as it is production code. Will check out `Shell_NotifyIcon`. Any other directions? @HansPassant

Comment: No luck with Shell_NotifyIcon. Does not do anything

Comment: Your dialog box code seems no problem. Without process A, can you get Process B (that Loads a DLL using LoadLibrary and calls a function that will invoke the DialogBox) successfully show the dialogbox?

Comment: A call to `MessageBox` works?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Sorry for the late reply. I have no way to invoke process B without process A. There are protocols that make it mandatory. But, I did recreate the scenario on my own separately, and yes, It worked there.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Nope. On debugging I found out that the function executes without error but hangs indefinitely as the message box is not visible.

Comment: Well then we can eliminate your dialog implementation, resource files or message loop. MessageBox only fails to display a message if the system is shutting down, or if the window is being successfully displayed, but on a separate Window Station / Desktop.

Comment: @ChrisBecke There is no window in any desktop, nor an entry in task manager or in the task bar. None. Nothing. Kinda weird

Comment: Whats the `wShowWindow` of your STARTUPINFO?

Comment: Not set. @ChrisBecke